# how to retrieve local json data to display it on a google map flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, google-maps

hello everyone I would like to recover Json data from a local file then display them on my google map . I tried many example but I did not succeed,please help me
this is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'VIVI ENERGY',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Set<Marker> allMarkers = {};
  GoogleMapController _controller;

  Future _future;
  Future<String> loadString() async {
    await rootBundle.loadString('assets/fileJson/shell.json');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _future = loadString();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: Text("VIVO ENERGY"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        ),
        drawer: new Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountName: new Text(""),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: Stack(children: [
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: FutureBuilder(
                future: _future,
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data.documents.isEmpty) {
                    return Text('changement');
                  } else {
                    List<dynamic> parsedJson = jsonDecode(snapshot.data);
                    allMarkers = parsedJson.map((element) {
                      var coordonnee = element['Coordonnees_gps'];
                      var coordonneeF = coordonnee.split(',');
                      var lat = double.parse(coordonneeF[0]);
                      var Lng = double.parse(coordonneeF[1]);
                      return Marker(
                          markerId: MarkerId(element['Nom']),
                          position: LatLng(lat, Lng));
                    }).toSet();
                  }

                  return GoogleMap(
                    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                        target: LatLng(5.316667, -4.033333), zoom: 15),
                    markers: Set.from(allMarkers),
                    onMapCreated: mapCreated,
                  );
                }),
          )
        ]));
  }

  void mapCreated(controller) {
    setState(() {
      _controller = controller;
    });
  }
}
```

I tried several method and I still cannot recover my data in local file I always have as a message the one at of the condition of! "snapshot.hasData"

Comment: do you get any error message? also did you add the file to the pubspec.yaml?

Comment: no I have no error in the pubspec.yaml and I add the file

Comment: do you mean you added the file to the yaml? can you please provide the yaml file?

Answer (score 0):

this is my pubspec.yaml

```
name: lecolis
description: Application de livraison par geolocalisation

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  http: ^0.13.1
  geolocator : ^7.0.1
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.2
  permission_handler: ^7.0.0
  modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.3



  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2


dev_dependencies:

  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
      - assets/img/gps.png
      - assets/img/icon.png
      - assets/img/shell.png
      - assets/img/badshell.png
      - assets/fileJson/shell.json
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```